# C# XML can't load indent value

Tags: c#

The code below is causing the " Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. " 
I like to keep the code indent(linebreak) but keep having the problem as mentioned above. I could use the TextReader to load the xml but it will remove the indent which i don't like it. If you know how to fix problem please let me know. Thanks

```
public XmlDocument MYXML()
  {
    XmlWriterSettings wSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
      wSettings.Indent = false;
      wSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
      XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, wSettings);// Write Declaration
      xw.WriteStartDocument();

      // Write the root node
      xw.WriteStartElement("Library");

      // Write the books and the book elements
      xw.WriteStartElement("Book");
      xw.WriteStartAttribute("BookType");
      xw.WriteString("Hardback");
      xw.WriteEndAttribute();

      xw.WriteStartElement("Title");
      xw.WriteString("Door Number Three");
      xw.WriteEndElement();
      xw.WriteStartElement("Author");
      xw.WriteString("O'Leary, Patrick");
      xw.WriteEndElement();

      xw.WriteEndElement();

      xw.WriteEndElement();

      // Close the document
      xw.WriteEndDocument();

      // Flush the write
      xw.Flush();

      Byte[] buffer = new Byte[ms.Length];
      buffer = ms.ToArray();
      string xmlOutput = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

      //The next 3 line works fine but it will remove the Indent from the XmlWriterSettings
      //TextReader tr = new StreamReader(ms);
      //ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      //xmlOutput = tr.ReadToEnd() + "";

      //Can't nload the  xmlOutput from  buffer
      XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
      xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlOutput);

      return xmldoc;
  }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the whole encoding round trip?

Comment: I really need to load the xml into the XMLDocument because I need to return the XmlDocument so it can be reused in multiple areas and to make it easier to manipulate

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlWriter` is writing a utf-8 byte-order mark to the stream. `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` doesn't account for this (since it's only supposed to occur in files) so the first character of the string becomes an invalid, unprintable character, which is what XmlDocument.LoadXml chokes on.

EDIT: Since you said you want to create an XmlDocument so you can reuse it, I recommend one of the following:

1. If using .Net 3.5 or newer, use `XDocument` which is much easier to use (I recommend this).
2. Create the XmlDocument directly by constructing nodes and adding them to the tree.
3. Create the XmlDocument directly from the writer by using XPathNavigator (`XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator.AppendChild()`)

Note that you can't easily add insignificant whitespace to an XmlDocument. Using `XDocument` and writing it to the output using `doc.Save(Response.Output)` is by far the easiest option if you want to have nicely formatted output.

Comment: I really need to load the xml into the XMLDocument because I need to return the XmlDocument so it can be reused in multiple areas and to make it easier to manipulate.

Comment: In that case, create the `XmlDocument` directly by creating nodes and appending children. Or if this is .Net 3.5 and newer, use `XDocument` instead which is much easier to work with. Writing it to a string first and then parsing it again is needlessly wasteful (though for future reference, if you must write XML to a string don't use a `MemoryStream`, create an `XmlWriter` that writes to a `StringBuilder` or `StringWriter` instead, but I again I don't recommend doing that here).